# Database sync with Eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save the input of some checkboxes.

I have a table users_cities as:

```
id_user | id_city
--------+---------
   1    |    1
   1    |    2
   2    |    1
```

And I have a view which brings three checkboxes.

**city1 city2 city3,** on that case for `id_user = 1` would bring city1 and city2 checked.

what I am trying to do is, if the user selects box 3 and uncheck box 2 or just select box 3, the Eloquent would recognise and sync the data with the database.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $city[] = \App\City::find($id);

    $input = Request::all();

    //Tried:      $city->sync($input)
    //Also tried: $city->delete(); $city->save($input);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I have the `id_user` on the `$city` variable and the cities on `$input` but I can't get this to work.

VIEW:

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('content')

    <h1>Atualizar cidades</h1>


    @foreach ($city as $citySelect)

        <?php $number[] = $citySelect->id_city; ?>

    @endforeach 

    {!! Form::model($city, ['route' => ['cities.update', $citySelect->id_user]]) !!}

    @foreach ($cidades as $cidadesnome)

        {!! Form::checkbox($cidadesnome->id, $cidadesnome->name, (in_array($cidadesnome->id, $number)), ['class' => 'field']) !!}{!! $cidadesnome->name !!}

    @endforeach

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> 
        Atualizar Cidades
    </button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

Relations:

```
public function cities() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('City', 'users_cities', 'id_city', 'id_user');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Users', 'users_cities', 'id_user', 'id_city');
}
```

Comment: Please show where you attempt to use the `$input` variable.

Comment: I just don't know how I can do,, I tried $city->sync($input).. tried also $city->delete(); and $city->save($input)

Comment: Well, edit the question to include your attempts.  Also be sure to include all relevant information, such as your model.

Comment: i edited the question with the relations.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the `id_user` on the `$city` variable and the cities on `$input` but I can't get this to work.

That is not posible since you used `$city[] = \App\City::find($id);` and therefore `$city` is not `id_user` but an array that contains one instance of `App\City`.

What you need to do in order to sync the cities of an user whose id is in `$id` is:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $user = \App\User::findOrFail($id);
    $input = Request::all();
    $user->cities()->sync($input['cities']);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

You also need to change your checkboxes name to send an array of cities and have the name `cities[]`

```
@foreach ($cidades as $cidadesnome)
    <label>
    {!! Form::checkbox('cities[]', $cidadesnome->id, (in_array($cidadesnome->id, $number)), ['class' => 'field']) !!}{!! $cidadesnome->name !!}
    </label>
@endforeach
```

All that assuming you defined the proper relationships in your models. I see you are not following [Eloquent naming convention](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) for your column names. I highly recommend you follow them. They will make your relationships definitions much easier.

Comment: it keeps giving me Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cities()... and i have it declared as     public function cities() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('City', 'users_cities', 'id_city', 'id_user');
    }

Comment: Show us please how did you defined your relationships in both *City* and *User* model